# Add extra icons to rocksolid icon picker

Tags: contao

Hi I need to add extra icons to rocksolid icon sets. I follwed the instructions in https://rocksolidthemes.com/de/contao/blog/iconfont-anpassen-icons-hinzufuegen and successfully downloaded the new icon set and copied to the desired folder. But the new icons are not showing in the picker. I need to know whether the new icons were lost when the rocksolid is upgraded? If yes, what is the remedy for this? Can I add more than one icon files in the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

> But the new icons are not showing in the picker.

This is probably a caching problem. Please try to delete all browser cache after replacing the font files in the template directory. Further make sure the new font files have the same font names as the original files ("replace" the original files in the template font folder). You also have to update/replace the font css file as stated at the end of the linked article:

Roughly translated: "To see the new icons in *Icon Picker* copy the file `style.css` of the downloaded font packet to the font folder of your template and rename it to `rocksolid-icons.css`. Delete `rocksolid-icons.html` if this file exists."

> I need to know whether the new icons were lost when the rocksolid is upgraded

The font files are part of the template and included in the template folder. So you should make a backup of the template folder before updating to a newer version of the used rocksolid template. After updating the rocksolid template you can again replace the font files and css within the template folder to get your own icons back in place...